# Split with map! doesn't work

Tags: ruby

Why map! doens't work with a splited string ?

```
str = "abcd"  
str.split('').map! { |x| x + "!" }
str # => "abcd"
```

I expected this would return `["a!","b!","c!","d!"]`

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work? You never assigned a reference to the array you are `map!`ping, so how can you look at it to check whether it works or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`str.split('')` returns a new array. Calling `.map!` against the new string does not change the original `str`.

Assigning the result of `str.split('')` back to `str`:

```
str = str.split('')
str.map! { |x| x + "!" }
str  # => ["a!", "b!", "c!", "d!"]
```

Or, assigning the whole result back to the `str`:

```
str = str.split('').map! { |x| x + "!" }
str  # => ["a!", "b!", "c!", "d!"]
```

**NOTE**

Using same variable for saving string initially, then saving array could confuse the reader of the code. You'd better to use different variable for array;

```
arr = str.split('')
arr.map! { |x| x + "!" }
arr  # => ["a!", "b!", "c!", "d!"]
```

Comment: @steenslag, Thank you for the correction. I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: OP's intent to store an array in a variable named `str` is pretty confusing, especially as it initially contains a string. This answer should probably try to propose an additional better version of the code with two distinct variables to clarify the intent.

Comment: @SirDarius, I agree. I will update the answer to include your suggestion. Thank you for the comment.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are updating in-place yes, but that array object that you waste because you don't save its instance anywhere.

```
characters = "abcd".split('')
characters.map! { |x| x + "!" }
characters
```

Note that you can move from `split('')` to `chars`

Answer (score 1):

You also can use [`#chars`:](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-chars)

```
> "abcd".chars.map { |x| x + '!' }
=> ["a!", "b!", "c!", "d!"]
```

Comment: I understand the reasoning behind the other answers as to stay as close as possible to the original implementation but this is the most readable solution in my opinion. Although in this case I would suggest using `each_char` or `map!`(like the other answers) instead to avoid the creation of a disposed `Array`